# Get date from DatePicker using c# in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, datepicker, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to insert date value in my database I have a class which have a date time attribute like this

```
public DateTime BookingDate { get; set; }
```

I have a date picker in my xaml page named datepicker . I want to insert only date value , How to get date using c#??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Date` Property , follow the documentation

```
  DateTimeOffset sourceTime = YourDatePicker.Date;
  BookingDate = sourceTime.DateTime;
```

To convert back to offset and bind to datetimepicker

```
   DateTime newBookingDate;
   newBookingDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(BookingDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
   DateTimeOffset bindTime = newBookingDate;
   YourDatePicker.Date = bindTime;
```

[`Adding a DatePicker (XAML)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308514.aspx)

Comment: cannnot convert DateTimeOffset to DateTime

Comment: Its just a matter of conversion, check my modified answer

Comment: similarly if i want to convert Timepicker value to Time then?

Comment: check my updated answer, also if you want more info check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546101(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry but last thing I have Timepicker , I want to get time only ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59494/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-user3814490).

Answer (score 0):

Using an MVVM Pattern:

View (XAML):

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding DateOffset, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

ViewModel (C#):

```
private DateTime Date { get; set; }
public DateTimeOffset DateOffset
{
    get { return DateTime.SpecifyKind(Date, DateTimeKind.Utc); }
    set { Date = value.DateTime; }
}
```